# Dictionary returned in Flask displays empty curly braces

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I'm trying to make a flask pipeline which receives data from a python file and sends the data to react which display them.

I currently am stuck trying to receive the data in flask after sending them via post to the URL: `localhost:5000/weather-data`

The data is being posted with this Code:

```
dummy_data = {'data': str(msg.payload.decode('iso-8859-1')),
              'timestamp': datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()}
response = requests.post(url, data=dummy_data)
print(response.text)
```

The print result is:

```
{"data": "{\"region\": \"Jokkmokk\", \"temp_now\": 8.91, \"weather_now\": \"bewölkt\", \"humidity\": 50, \"wind\": 24}", 
  "timestamp": "2021-02-24T17:23:15.347058"}
```

Which is all right but then i try to receive the data and return it on the flask side with this code:

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def test():
    return 'HelloWorld'


@app.route('/weather-data', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def weather_data():
    try:
        data = request.form.to_dict()
        print(data)
        return data
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', debug=True, port=5000)
```

This runs normally through and my print(data) gives the exact same dictionary back but if i take a look at `localhost:5000/weather-data` i only see empty curly braces `{}`

As a Test i tried to return the data without receivng them first with this code:

```
@app.route('/weather-data', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def weather_data():
   return {"data": "{\"region\": \"Fishermans City\", \"temp_now\": 6.87, \"weather_now\": \"st\\u00fcrmisch\", "humidity\": 52, \"wind\": 58}",
           "timestamp": "2021-02-23T18:32:49.120861"}
```

Like this it perfectly worked and showed the Data on the website.

**Edit:**

I think this is a stupid question for some of you but because i am kinda new to this i wanted to ask if it is possible that the Data is on the Page but when i reload the Page it overwrites the data with empty curly braces?

If yes is there a way that i can keep them on the Page until i make another Post with new data?

Comment: You aren't returning anything on your first code. You are only printing it. You would need to return `e` to send it back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [jsonify](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.json.jsonify)

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask import jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

data = dict()

@app.route('/')
def test():
    return 'HelloWorld'


@app.route('/weather-data', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def weather_data():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        global data
        data = request.form.to_dict()
        return jsonify(data), 200
    else:
        return jsonify(data), 200


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', debug=True, port=5000)
```

Comment: Thank you as well with your code i saw that it first printed the data normally (only in the Console) but when i Reloaded the localhost page it probably changed the data to empty curly braces
Do you know e way to permanently have the data there until i make another Post with new data?

Comment: the data object is lost when you reload the page, you need to hold the data in a variable, I updated the answer

Comment: Thank you so much really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `json`?

```
response = requests.post(url, json=dummy_data)
```

and

```
data = request.json
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion i tried it out but it had the same Result meaning when i reloaded the localhost page it showed empty curly braces